# Primitive recursivness of a function. How does the function work?

Tags: logic, computability, recursion

So, I need some help with an homework assignment.

Firstly: understanding the following function:
$h(x) = \prod_{m=0}^{f(x)} m*f(m)$

From my limited knowledge of the product of sequences my guess is that it works this way(output wise) ( $'$ is the successor function):

$h(x) = \prod_{m=0}^{f(x)} m*f(m) = (m * f(m)) * (m' * f(m'))...(m^x * f(m^x))$

where $x$ in $m^x$ is the result of $f(x)$, i.e. if $x = 2$ we will have $m'$ and $m''$.

Secondly: Showing that the function is primitive recursive. 
This is my first try at defining the function with recursion and im pretty unsure if I did succeed:

$h(x,0) = f(x,g(0))$
$h(x,y') = h(x,g(y)) * f(x,g(y'))$

A pointer or two would be appriciated. Best regards.

EDIT:
$h(0) = k(f(0))$
$h(x') = h(x) * k(f(x'))$

Comment: No, it means $(0\cdot f(0))\cdot (1\cdot f(1))\cdot(2\cdot f(2)\cdots(f(x)\cdot f(f(x))$. There is no $m$ in the unfolding, because that is a dummy variable bound by the indexed-product notation and not visible from the outside.

Comment: **Hint:** The first step would be to define $h(x)=k(f(x))$; then what you need to implement is $k(y)=\prod_{m=0}^y m\cdot f(m)$ which you can make using primitive recursion.

Comment: Your definition-by-primitive recursion is not quite right. You cannot insert a $g$ in the recursive invocation of $h$ -- the arguments to the recursive invocation must be exactly the same as the left-hand side _except_ with the prime on the recursion parameter removed -- so $h(x,y)$ rather than $h(x,g(y))$.

Comment: Thanks for the replies @HenningMakholm ! Lets see if I understood you correctly:  
The first comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification, but one thing i'm noticing here is that we will always have a $(0*f(0)) ... * (f(x) * f(f(x)))$ thus the end product will always be a zero $(0 * x = 0)$ correct? For this I could use the zero function in my function definition(Or maybe I NEED to)?

Comment: The hint you gave me is abit puzzling, (that might show that I'm more uncomfortable with p.r. functions than i thought). But here is a guess on what you are referring to:  
The first step is the base case I assume, but you always want to start with 0 in the base case afaik, thus it would be $h(0) = k(f(0))$  
But then we have the recursion step, which would turn out something like $h(x') = h(x) * k(f(x'))$.
  I'm noticing now that one of my mistakes was to use $h(x,y)$ for the function $h(x)$, 2 variables doesn't equal 1.

Comment: x @00sdf0: Everything collapsing to zero is a very nice observation. I hadn't noticed that. This means that a complete and correct answer to the exercise would be, **"the function is p.r. because it is the zero function, which is p.r. by definition"**. For good measure you should probably also attempt to give a definition of $h_1(x)=\prod_{m=1}^{f(x)} mf(m)$ anyway ...

Comment: x @00sdf0: No, I think you're misunderstanding the hint. I'm proposing _first_ to show that $k(y)=\prod_{m=1}^y ,mf(m)$ is primitive recursive: $$\begin{align}k(0)&= 1 \\ k(m+1) &= k(m)\cdot (m+1)f(m+1)\end{align}$$ Once you have defined $k$ you can define your desired $h$ by substitution as $h(x)=k(f(x))$. The definition of $h$ itself would _not_ by the primitive recursion scheme.